# Can I license my package under Creative Commons

Tags: packages, licensing

A while ago I made a package in order to generate nice theroem boxes for the redaction of some lecture notes I made for my school (voluntarily, as a student).

Today I realized that my school were using this package everywhere and without my permission.

I would like to license this package using Creative Commons (I'm very happy to let everyone use my package, but not without my permission, especcially for what they are doing with it).

T**he problem is that my package uses some other packages**, like xkeyval, ifthen or tikz. Most of them are under LPPL, and **I don't know if I can license my work with my conditions knowing that it uses other pieces under specific licensing**...

I hope that my question is clear : I'm not really fluent in English.

Thank you,
Flyerjet

Comment: Sorry, but this is a legal question and thus off-topic not only for us but cross-network. (Legal issues depend on where you are in the world, and real legal advice is a complex area.)

Comment: AFAIK Creative Commons is [not suitable for software](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/FAQ#Can_I_use_a_Creative_Commons_license_for_software.3F).

Comment: Schools generally own all what their students write, be it homework, term papers, theses, whatever. So it is probable that you (implicitly) wrote the package for your school (more or less like a work for hire). Ask a lawyer.